# How can I see the 'As of <date>' in a Report?

Tags: reporting, dashboard

All Dashboards currently show the 'As of ' as below:
[image: Salesforce Dashboard]

How can I get this to show for all Reports as well?

[image]

Comment: For your purposes (if it's for what you are showing), you could likely just use a custom date range to find logins between that range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have an as of date on the report. The difference is that dashboards are cached, so you need to know how out of date the data is. A report is real time, the moment you run or export it. There's no real need for an as of date. However, if you run a report and export it, the exported file will include the run time in XLS mode, or you could check the file's create time stamp attribute.